# wp8 - deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I'm deploying my application built on cordova 5.4.1 in windows phone 8.1. I'm getting error while using any plugins. I'm getting the following error in my console:

```
deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.

Channel not fired: onPluginsReady

Channel not fired: onCordovaReady
```

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

@Chirag,
occasionally a plugin will have a problem firing correctly.

1. Remove all plugins.
2. Build. Test.
3. Add a plugin. Build. Test. Repeat.

You may find a faulty plugin. If so, I'll show you how to report it. If not, let me know.